# I have API key, but still getting MissingKeyMapError

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Like the title says the console is telling me I have a missing API key although I have one right where google docs says to put it.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My Google Map</title>
    <style>
        #map{
            height:400px;
            width:100%;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <h1>My Google Map</h1>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
        function initMap(){
            var options = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: {lat:42.3601, lng:-71.0589}
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
        }
    </script>


    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?           
        key=Key_is_here&callback=initMap">
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have no error in this code. Can you please try in the incognito window?

Answer (score 1):

All Google Maps JavaScript API applications require authentication.

```
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?           
        key=Key_is_here&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

replace src script tag by this : `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=Past YOUR API KEY"></script>`

Comment: _"I have a missing API key **although I have one right where google docs says to put it**"_

Comment: I don't see how your code differs from OP's. `async` and `defer` don't make any difference rather than blocking the load.

Comment: @Asif Thank you, it took away the error but now it does not display. Do you have any idea why that is?

Comment: @Adam I'm not sure I'm just learning javascript but it did take away the error just now nothing is on the screen other than the H3 header.

Comment: Nevermind the error is still there it took awhile for it to pop up.

Answer (score 0):

You have white space in the API include URL. This is incorrect (has white space in the API include after the "?"):

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?           
    key=Key_is_here&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

This works for me:

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Key_is_here&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

[Working example (with my key)](http://www.geocodezip.com/SO_20170930_MapKeyMissingA.html)